# Anchoring Controls in Web Page Just Like WinForm Applications

Tags: asp.net, .net, css, web

I am new to CSS and also new to web development.

Controls in the windows applications has a property called anchor, you may set which part of control to be resized when resizing the parent container. I am looking for the same property in the web page.

Let me provide an example:

Suppose we have a `textbox`, a `button` and a `label` in a row, my question is how to give the `label` and `button` a **fixed size** (say 100px) and make the `textbox` fill the space up to **100%**.

A code snippet could be like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left; width:100%;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:100px;">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"></asp:Button></div>
    <div style="float:right; width:100px;">
        <asp:Label ID="Lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>        
</div>
```

Just note that the sample code is wrong and forces the button and label into a new row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="75%" Style="float: left;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="test" Width="10%" Style="float: right;" runat="server">
    </asp:Button>
    <asp:Label ID="Lbl1" Text="test" Width="10%" Style="float: right;" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Comment: it results in TWO separate lines! I want them to be in the same line (only one line).

Comment: float: left; width: 85%; style for textbox's div

Comment: setting to 85%, when the page is getting smaller, the components jump to the second row.

Comment: it causes the button and label to resize, I want them fixed and only the textbox resized pal! :-) just like anchoring in windows forms

Answer (score 0):

Using table did the trick

```
<table style="width:100%">
   <tr>
      <td style="width:100%"> TextBox Here </td>
      <td style="width:1px"> label Here </td>
      <td style="width:1px"> button Here </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```